# nativescript-couchbase-plugin querying

Tags: nativescript, couchbase, couchbase-lite, nativescript-plugin

I'm trying to use [nativescript-couchbase-plugin](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-couchbase-plugin).
Here is my code:

```
whereArray.push({ property: "type_id", comparison: "equalTo", value: typeId });
return itemsDb.query({
     select: [],
     where: whereArray,
     order: [{property: "rating", direction: "desc"}],
     limit: this.PAGE_SIZE,
     offset: page * this.PAGE_SIZE
});
```

Everything works fine: condition in where clause, ordering, limit and offset.
But I want to add something new to my condition and I'm trying to do this:

```
whereArray.push({ property: "title", comparison: "like", value: "some name"});
or
whereArray.push({ property: "filters", comparison: "in", value: [1,2,3]});
```

And these cases don't work. Neither of them. The only one that works is the first one with **type_id**

So the question is - how to use where array to query corresponding data?

Data Sample:

```
{
    "type_id": 2,
    "title": "some name",
    "regionId": 372,
    "uid": 16177,
    "filters": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
},
```

P.S. There is an [issue](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-couchbase-plugin/issues/28) inside original repository. But it has no activity at all.

Comment: Can you also post some sample data / documents to help us understand the query better?

Comment: I've updated the post with some my example data.

Answer (score 1):

I must agree the plugin documentation could be better. But if you go through the TypeScript declaration, you will find the issue with your code.

When you are adding multiple where conditions, you must include a logical operator.

```
 import {
    Couchbase,
    QueryLogicalOperator,
    QueryComparisonOperator
 } from "nativescript-couchbase-plugin";


const database = new Couchbase("my-database");

// Insert docs for testing
const documentId = database.createDocument({
    type_id: 2,
    title: "some name",
    regionId: 372,
    uid: 16177,
    filters: [1, 2, 3]
});
console.log(documentId); 

// Query
const results = database.query({
    select: [],
    where: [
        {
            property: "type_id",
            comparison: "equalTo",
            value: 2,
            logical: QueryLogicalOperator.AND
        },
        {
            property: "filters",
            comparison: "in",
            value: [1, 2, 3]
        }
    ],
    order: [{ property: "rating", direction: "desc" }],
    limit: 10
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: I've added it. And I solved my problem with logical operators, but not with subquery: I want to search only [1] in document that has field filters: [1, 2, 3]. Also I haven't find out a way to use fuzzy search via this plugin. I tried 'like' operator with * and without it.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean. After adding logical operator the queries in your OP works.

Comment: what about searching subquery in Couchbase?

Comment: Atention: the logical operator must be on the SECOND condition! (At least for me, only worked that way - on Nativescript-vue - Android)